# Upsert changing row_key (SERIAL)?

Tags: postgresql

I am typically using a function to generate an upsert statement to feed a dataframe (row by row) into Postgres. This seems to work as intended, but I have noticed that SERIAL columns have a new number assigned to them. Is that desired or should I change something? So my earliest rows like row 1 might be row 30,128 or something now.

```
def create_update_query(final_columns, primary_key, table):
    """This creates an UPSERT statement to replace values if there is a conflict with the primary key"""
    columns = ', '.join([f'{col}' for col in final_columns])
    constraint = ', '.join([f'{col}' for col in primary_key])
    placeholder = ', '.join([f'%({col})s' for col in final_columns])
    updates = ', '.join([f'{col} = EXCLUDED.{col}' for col in final_columns])
    query = f"""INSERT INTO {table} ({columns}) 
                VALUES ({placeholder}) 
                ON CONFLICT ({constraint}) 
                DO UPDATE SET {updates};"""
    query.split()
    query = ' '.join(query.split())
    return query
```

- final_columns = the dataframe (df.columns) and it does not include a row_key or insert_timestamp (both of these are created by postgres)
- primary_key are the columns used for the PRIMARY KEY in postgres to prevent duplication

Example output query:

```
'INSERT INTO example.fact_table (report_date, employee_id, state_count, state_time) VALUES (%(report_date)s, %(employee_id)s, %(state_count)s, %(state_time)s) ON CONFLICT (report_date, employee_id) DO UPDATE SET report_date = EXCLUDED.report_date, employee_id = EXCLUDED.employee_id, state_count = EXCLUDED.state_count, state_time = EXCLUDED.state_time;'
```

This is fed to the database by:

```
for row in insert_values:
    cursor.execute(create_update_query(final_columns, primary_key, table), row)
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: I don't understand. Either there is a primary key collision, then the primary key won't change, or there isn't. Ora are you talking about the physical row location (`ctid`)?

Comment: A primary key might be the employee_id and report_date. If there is a collision, the row is updated as expected. I am referring to only the row_id serial key which keeps increasing for the same employee_id and report_date combination - I was expecting a static ID where row_id 99 would always refer to John Smith on 2017-10-01, but that is not the case for me

Comment: can you post the table schema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say *SERIAL columns have a new number assigned to them* I believe you mean that the sequence value is increased even when there is a conflict, by the number of conflicting rows.

If so, this is expected behavior - see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAM3SWZQMfR6Zfe3A0Nr4ddko8xZrijAuQQ%3DEcGjGeJSs2piAXA%40mail.gmail.com).

One way of dealing with this problem is to first check whether there might be a conflicting situation (with a CTE) and then proceed to insert or update, depending on needs.

This won't cause the sequence number to increase on conflicts but it won't be any longer an *upsert* in the traditional sense (which is a non issue).

Comment: Yes, for example, a case was opened on 10/01 and it is assigned row_key 122. On 10/05 the case was re-opened and the row is updated, so the row_key is 298, and then on 10/11, another change happens. The unique identifier is the case_id anyway, but I just wanted to be certain the SERIAL columns were supposed to change and it was not due to my Python scripts.

Comment: If you don't mind having holes in your sequences then there is nothing to worry about, you can keep on as is.

Comment: Note: UPSERT (`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT UPDATE  ...`) cannot simply be replaced with a CTE solution under concurrent load. This would be an *issue*. It's the reason, this feature was introduced in the first place.